# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to c#

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, oracle11g

ESTE ES EL PROCEDIMIENTO EN LA BASE DE DATOS.

(Translation from Google Translate: THIS IS THE PROCEDURE IN THE DATABASE.)

```
create or replace procedure sp_validarusuario(v_name IN varchar2, v_clave IN varchar2, v_validacion OUT varchar2)
IS
BEGIN
 Select 'OK' into v_validacion from usuario where password = v_clave and nombre = v_name;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
  v_validacion := 'NOOK';
END sp_validarusuario;
/
```

ERROR EN C# AL MOMENTO DE EJECUTAR EL SP.

(Translation per Google Translate: C# ERROR IN THE TIME OF EXECUTING THE SP)

[Imagen Error en C#](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4c-CKVxEwBoanJ2X3hGWUR4S2M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How about english language?

Answer (score 1):

In your C# code use this:

```
cmd.Parameters.add("v_validacion",OracleDbType.varchar2).Direction=ParameterDirection.Output
```

Instead of this :

```
cmd.Parameters.add("v_validacion",OracleDbType.varchar2).Direction=ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
```

refer to [ParameterDirection Enumeration MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The MSDN description is slightly misleading in the context of Oracle. You cannot have a *return* parameter for stored procedure. In Oracle, only functions have a (single) return parameter.

Comment: @Codo: you are correct that procedures cannot have a RETURN value; however, your implication that procedures cannot have `OUT` parameters is wrong. Procedures can have as many `OUT` parameters as you care to declare, subject to the limit of 65536 parameters to/from any one procedure, cursor, or function. The big problem I see in the example code above is that the enumeration in question is `ParameterDirection`, not `ParametreDirection` (although the documentation reference has it spelled correctly).

Comment: I haven't implied anything regarding *out* parameters.

Comment: @BobJarvis `ParametreDirection` was just a typing error, thank you for notifying me, I edited it.

Comment: @Codo - since the `cmd.Parameters.add` call in this answer relates to an `OUT` parameter defined in OP's procedure I thought you must have been referring to that.